# How can I activate this kind of menus in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I use anaconda 3 specifically spyder and during writing codes, I need this kind of menu to be showed automatically. I mean the menu that suggests keywords. Even if I press (CTRL+space) it doesn't appear. how can I activate it?

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4587#issuecomment-420648724) in Spyder IDE as discussed in the Spyder's official [GitHub Page](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4587)
Many people have tried various solutions and they have got it working.

[Solution 1:](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4587#issuecomment-357411444)

- Uninstall Anaconda from the control panel
- Restart Computer
- Download and install anconda from [https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/]
- Restart again before it you start anaconda.
- Done.

Solution 2:
sudo pip3 install rope

Let us know if it worked. @Alok Thanks for sharing it with me.